# extract strings after a certain pattern and store them

Tags: python, regex, file-io, pattern-matching

I have a bunch of outputs that look like:

```
 004400:  0x10000000 (268435456)
 004404:  0x0f010000 (251723776)
 004408:  0x0c018000 (201424896)
 00440c:  0x0c019000 (201428992)
 004410:  0x0b01a000 (184655872)
 004414:  0x0901a800 (151103488)
 004418:  0x0701aa00 (117549568)
 00441c:  0x0701aa80 (117549696)
 004420:  0x0701ab00 (117549824)
 004424:  0x0701ab80 (117549952)
 004428:  0x0701ac00 (117550080)
   .          .           .
   .          .           .
   .          .           .
 0047f4:  0x00000000 (0)
 0047f8:  0x00000000 (0)
 0047fc:  0x00000000 (0)
```

So I want to extract the contents in the second column (e.g: `0x10000000`) after the addresses (first column). Later I need to write them back, so that would be better if they can be stored in a file and then read back as a list. I'm new to Python, and want to find a library that's easy to use. Some examples would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want a specific pattern or just get all the rows in the column?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham all the rows, but only the second column

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no, the dots mean the lines in between, I just didn't list them all.

Comment: so you have an input file as above, you want to get all the values in the second column and write those to another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 1 that returns the second column.

```
(?<=:)\s*(0x.*?\b)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gL5eD9/1)

---

Try this one as well

```
[^:]\s*(0x.*?\b)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gL5eD9/2)

Description:

```
(?<=:)     Positive Lookbehind to match the character : literally
[^:]       match a single character that is not :
\s*        match any white space character 
.*?        matches any character (except newline) lazily
\b         assert position at a word boundary
```

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'[^:]\s*(0x.*?\b)')
test_str = ...

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

---

Have a look at this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gL5eD9/3) as well to group all the columns.

Comment: @hwnd don't know much more about the input pattern that OP is looking for. Thanks this is also an answer but look at the third column `(0)` that is different from previous ones.

Comment: Yea I agree, OP stated second column though but who really knows.

Comment: @hwnd only OP knows.:) There are lots of ways to match second column.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the content of the second column there's no need for a regex here. You can do:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    col2 = [line.split()[1] for line in f]
```

This will give you the content of the second column as a list `col2`. If you want to write these to a new file, you can do:

```
with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in col2:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to extract the second column? I think there should be a pattern matching here, such as 004*: (.*) ? The outputs are from memory, there's no file in the first place.

Comment: @JFreebird Uhm, the list `col2` contains the second column exactly as you specified. If you want something else I don't understand your question.